# Show summary of all customizations

Tags: administration

I recently took over a very, very degraded salesforce org (we are talking about 2 years of no maintenance at all and a total of 4 years of no professional admins/devs).

I'm currently looking for an easy way to assess the current "implementation".

I know of Setup > System Overview and the Optimizer, but I'm looking for a more detailed view than what the suggestions in the Optimizer provide. I am thinking of something like a summary that shows me how many workflow rules, validation rules, custom fields, etc there are on standard objects (much like the Object Limits on custom objects). Maybe also a reporting that analyzes the usage of said fields, e.g. out of "10k records, only 100 have data in field x"

Do you know of solution (AppExchange?) that could help me with that? Or if not, what would be your recommended approach?

/edit: I found the regular Object Limits on standard objects. So only the requirement for **advanced usage/limits** of remains.